# ng-pattern to validate password match

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I use this to validate a password that has to have 8 characters, one capital letter and numeric but when I add an asterisk to it it throws an error saying passwords do not match, this only happens using the asterisk.

Any help will be appreciate it

```
ng-pattern="/(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/
```

You can test here: http://regexr.com/3c65b

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like that:

```
ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[\d\W])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])[^.\n].{7,}$/"
```

or more hand-driven:

```
ng-pattern="/^(?=[^\d\W]*[\d\W])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])[^.\n].{7,}$/"
```